# Double to String conversion issue in some of the iPhone in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnumberformatter

I am facing issue in double to string conversion it occurs one or two users iPhone , from my side it is working as expected

my double value - 10.890000000000001,

expected string output = "10.89",

but some of users iPhone the output is - "1089" ( **.** is missed)

in debugging I cannot reproduce this, it working as expected, I didn't find any cause of this issue, here I attached my code, Thanks in Advance

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundCeiling];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleValue]];
```

Comment: What is the locale of those users? Are they in parts of the world that use `.` as a thousands separator?

Comment: `Locale`  That's what I was just going to say.

Comment: locale of users is `en_US ` USA

Comment: Why is this tagged with Swift?

Comment: @MartinR maybe some of swift dev facing this issue so

Comment: ensure once whats the OS version that users

Comment: Most non-english speaking countries by law use `.` as a thousands separator – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg
So the use case for `.` & `,` is reversed. Internationally developers are more used to English speaking countries notation due to habit of dealing with floats in code.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes it was iOS 14.2 and 14.4 and 14.3

Comment: Is there maybe some other code that might be causing it to lose the `.`?  No matter the locale there should be either a `.` or a `,` there... there shouldn't be *nothing* there.  Did you verify with lldb or an NSLog perhaps?

Comment: this code has no problem, maybe try to check the doubleValue's calculation, is it really correct as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best practice but you can try following, it should work for you.

```
double doubleValue = 10.89;
    
NSString * numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", doubleValue];
NSLog(@"numberString = %@", numberString);
```

Comment: @Jayaseelan Kumarasamy - Did you try this?